# Error when trying to install websocket module in NodeJS through npm

Tags: node.js, websocket, npm

I got the following error when I tried to install `websocket` module in NodeJS. I'm trying on an Ubuntu 12.04 machine.

```
ubuntu@domU-12-31-39-14-1A-A1:/var/www$ npm install websocket
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/websocket
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/websocket

> websocket@1.0.8 install /var/www/node_modules/websocket
> node install.js

[websocket v1.0.8] Attempting to compile native extensions.
[websocket v1.0.8]
Native code compile failed!!
Please note that this module DOES NOT REQUIRE the native components
and will still work without them, though not quite as efficiently.

On Windows, native extensions require Visual Studio and Python.
On Unix, native extensions require Python, make and a C++ compiler.
Start npm with --websocket:verbose to show compilation output (if any).
websocket@1.0.8 node_modules/websocket
```

The command I used to install `websocket` module is `npm install websocket`. Can somebody advise what is going wrong?

Comment: Have you checked your ./var/www/node_modules/websocket folder? It looks to me like it installed fine, but was just unable to add the native extensions due to incompatibility.

Answer (score 1):

Check if python and make are installed.
I haven't done this on Ubuntu but on Windows7 the same error appears. This [post](https://github.com/Worlize/WebSocket-Node/issues/28) is helpful. I tried with npm install websocket@1.0.3 and it worked.